# SQL Querying dates using only month and year

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query my table to return the 'sessions' that are booked for june 2017. (06-17)
this is my query so far:

```
SELECT SESSIONID,SESSIONDATE,SESSIONPRICE
FROM CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE SESSIONDATE = TO_DATE('06-17', 'MM-YY')
ORDER BY SESSIONDATE DESC;
```

however this returns nothing. it does work if i query a specific date, for example

```
WHERE SESSIONDATE = TO_DATE('6-06-17', 'DD-MM-YY')
```

my table data looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES ('SS01','B1','R1','S1',TO_DATE('3-05-17','DD-MM-YY'),12.50);
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES ('SS02','B2','R1','S2',TO_DATE('4-06-17','DD-MM-YY'),19.45);
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES ('SS03','B1','R2','S2',TO_DATE('13-05-17','DD-MM-YY'),12.69);
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES ('SS04','B4','R2','S4',TO_DATE('13-06-17','DD-MM-YY'),14.56);
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES ('SS05','B3','R2','S5',TO_DATE('23-05-17','DD-MM-YY'),14.56);
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES ('SS06','B3','R1','S5',TO_DATE('3-06-17','DD-MM-YY'),16.32);
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES ('SS07','B4','R2','S3',TO_DATE('13-05-17','DD-MM-YY'),21.78);
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES ('SS08','B1','R2','S2',TO_DATE('6-06-17','DD-MM-YY'),16.82);
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES ('SS09','B2','R3','S4',TO_DATE('13-05-17','DD-MM-YY'),17.90);
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES ('SS10','B4','R1','S3',TO_DATE('6-06-17','DD-MM-YY'),16.37);
```

any help is greatly appreciated. thank you so much !

Comment: Run `select TO_DATE('06-17', 'MM-YY') from dual;` and you'll understand why your query doesn't work the way you think it ought to. A DATE must have a day component, and it we don't provide one Oracle will default it.

Comment: You need to correctly tag RDBMS. Because, solution differs on each RDBMS

Comment: You should better know the difference between `Oracle` and `SQL Server`. They are not at all same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Oracle`, then use [**`TO_CHAR`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) instead.

Example:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(SESSIONDATE,'MM-YY')='06-17'
```

**[>>>Demo<<<](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b2b6e/4)**

---

If you are using `SQL Server`, you can use **[`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)**

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), SESSIONDATE, 12) ='1706'
```

Above conversion will return as `'YYMM'`.

Comment: I tried to use TO_CHAR, but since its in sql server, it comes up with unknown command. ive tried CAST and CONVERT but neither of those work either :(

Comment: You tagged `Oracle` in your question. How are you expecting us to answer in `SQL SERVER` ?

Comment: @JamieSimpson If you were unable to `TO_CHAR` in SQL Server, then can you explain. How did you executed insert query, which has `TO_DATE` ??

Comment: i'm not sure, i'm using oracle SQL developer, and TO_DATE worked but TO_CHAR comes up with unknown command

Comment: @JamieSimpson Are you joking ? You have no idea, which database are you using and you are writing query. ????

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, i know its frustrating, i'm quite new to this haha
i ran the updated one, it came up with this error
Error starting at line : 100 in command -
SELECT SESSIONID,SESSIONDATE,SESSIONPRICE
FROM CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), SESSIONDATE, 12) ='1706'
ORDER BY SESSIONDATE DESC
Error at Command Line : 102 Column : 15
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @JamieSimpson `ORA-00936:` error indicate you are using Oracle. So, solution, which I provided earlier MUST run without any issue.

Comment: @JamieSimpson I have also posted Demo link, which works fine.

Comment: UGH... tried the first solution again, worked perfectly, thank you so so much ravi you saved my life, i dont know why it didnt work before but it does now

Answer (score 1):

Truncate the date to the "month" level and compare that way:

```
SELECT SESSIONID,SESSIONDATE,SESSIONPRICE
  FROM CONFERENCESESSION
  WHERE TRUNC(SESSIONDATE, 'MONTH') = TO_DATE('06-2017', 'MM-YYYY')
  ORDER BY SESSIONDATE DESC;
```

[SQLFiddle here to see what the effects are](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/846a2/1).

By the way, this is a VERY expensive query in that you need to execute a function against every row in the table. If you don't have a function-based index specifically in place to service this query it may be very slow. A better method is to use a ranged query, as shown below:

```
SELECT SESSIONID,SESSIONDATE,SESSIONPRICE
  FROM CONFERENCESESSION
  WHERE SESSIONDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-06-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                        AND TO_DATE('01-07-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
  ORDER BY SESSIONDATE DESC;
```

Here the end-points of the query ('01-06-2017' and '01-07-2017') only need to be computed once - after that Oracle uses simple DATE comparisons which perform well.

Keep in mind that when using `BETWEEN` the endpoints are both considered to be "in" the range, so we need to subtract one second from (in this case) July 1st to ensure that the query doesn't pick up any unwanted rows with a SESSIONDATE in the first second of July.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract month and year and pass it in where clause. You write query as follow,

```
 SELECT SESSIONID,SESSIONDATE,SESSIONPRICE, EXTRACT (Month from SESSIONDATE) as SESSIONDATE_Month,EXTRACT (Year from SESSIONDATE) as SESSIONDATE_Year from CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE  EXTRACT (Month from SESSIONDATE) = 06 and EXTRACT (Year from SESSIONDATE) = 2017 
ORDER BY SESSIONDATE DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your table contains the following data (using MS SQL server 2016):

```
SS01    B1  R1  S1  03/05/2017 00:00:00 12.50
SS02    B2  R1  S2  04/06/2017 00:00:00 19.45
SS03    B1  R2  S2  13/05/2017 00:00:00 12.69
SS04    B4  R2  S4  13/06/2017 00:00:00 14.56
SS05    B3  R2  S5  23/05/2017 00:00:00 14.56
SS06    B3  R1  S5  03/06/2017 00:00:00 16.32
SS07    B4  R2  S3  13/05/2017 00:00:00 21.78
SS08    B1  R2  S2  06/06/2017 00:00:00 16.82
SS09    B2  R3  S4  13/05/2017 00:00:00 17.90
SS10    B4  R1  S3  06/06/2017 00:00:00 16.37
```

You could use a query that looks a bit like ...

```
select sessionid sid_, sessiondate date_, sessionprice price_
from cs
where month(sessiondate) = 6
and year(sessiondate) = 2017
order by sessiondate desc;
```

Output (all "June" sessions)

```
sid_    date_               price_
SS04    13/06/2017 00:00:00 14.56
SS08    06/06/2017 00:00:00 16.82
SS10    06/06/2017 00:00:00 16.37
SS02    04/06/2017 00:00:00 19.45
SS06    03/06/2017 00:00:00 16.32
```

See [dbfiddle here.](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f617df39e14f92c231fd12dfb14c6a3c)

Comment: `MONTH` and `YEAR` are not Oracle functions.

Comment: @MTO: I know.  Apparently, there was some confusion - the question had been tagged "Oracle", and then the OP commented that the presented solution did not work under MS SQL (see Ravi's comments).  That's why I have added this.